# Crash on ffmpeg avcodec_encode_video in a Console app

Tags: c++, crash, ffmpeg

I want make an encoder which encode a raw image into h263 format.But after loading and initializing ffmpeg library I got crash on avcodec_encode_video for a demo image.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    avcodec_register_all();
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y, got_output;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket pkt;

    int out_size, size, outbuf_size;

    AVFrame *picture;
    uint8_t *outbuf, *picture_buf;

    AVRational rp;   

    rp.den = 1;
    rp.num = 25;
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_H263);

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    picture= avcodec_alloc_frame();
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 352;
    c->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    //c->time_base= (AVRational){1,25};
    c->time_base = rp;
    c->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
    c->max_b_frames=1;
    c->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    avcodec_open(c, codec);


    outbuf_size = 100000;
    outbuf = (uint8_t*)malloc(outbuf_size);
    size = c->width * c->height;
    picture_buf = (uint8_t*)malloc((size * 3) / 2); /* size for YUV 420 */

    picture->data[0] = picture_buf;
    picture->data[1] = picture->data[0] + size;
    picture->data[2] = picture->data[1] + size / 4;
    picture->linesize[0] = c->width;
    picture->linesize[1] = c->width / 2;
    picture->linesize[2] = c->width / 2;

    /* encode 1 second of video */
    for(i=0;i<25;i++) {
        fflush(stdout);
        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for(y=0;y<c->height;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width;x++) {
                picture->data[0][y * picture->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }
        /* Cb and Cr */
        for(y=0;y<c->height/2;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width/2;x++) {
                picture->data[1][y * picture->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                picture->data[2][y * picture->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }
        /* encode the image */

        **Crash is here** --->                 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, picture);

        printf("encoding frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, out_size);
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);
    }
    /* get the delayed frames */
    for(; out_size; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);
        out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, NULL);
        printf("write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, out_size);
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);
    }
    /* add sequence end code to have a real mpeg file */
    outbuf[0] = 0x00;
    outbuf[1] = 0x00;
    outbuf[2] = 0x01;
    outbuf[3] = 0xb7;
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, 4, f);
    fclose(f);
    free(picture_buf);
    free(outbuf);

    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    av_free(picture);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Yes I did and as it is a sample example from ffmpeg ,my expectation was to run it smoothly.I can't understand why it crash ,although the input is demo data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by adding the new version of ffmpeg.

Keep the library up-to-date and the problem should go away.

Comment: You really should mention which version it was.